# Firefox SDK page-mod onAttach event not firing even though code is injected

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a firefox extension using the addon SDK 1.15 and part of it should inject a script into http://linustechtips.com/*. This is an extract from my code:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var data = self.data;

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.linustechtips.com",
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("linustechtips-injection.js")],
  contentScriptWhen:"ready",
  onAttach: function(worker){
    notificationQueue.push({title:"attached",text:"attached to ltt",});
    worker.port.emit("dataUrl",data.url());
  },
});
```

and the content script contains:

```
var dataUrl="";
self.port.on("dataUrl",function(data){dataUrl=data;setTimeout(function(){console.log(dataUrl);},5000)});
console.log("injected");

var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(); //jquery was conflicting and causing issues
```

Followed by some more code, but it runs, and if it is put insde the self.port.on(...) code, it never runs (the self.port.on(..) is never called because the onAttach is never called.

But while the script is injected as it should (in fact, it appears to run twice for some reason), the onAttach code is never called (it should display a desktop notification and emit the data.url().)

There are no errors logged to the firefox console.

The url of the site I'm using to test is http://linustechtips.com

Comment: Are you sure `include: "*.linustechtips.com"` matches `http://linustechtips.com`?

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I assumed that, since the code appears to be being injected, it was a match. I did have quite a bit of trouble trying to make it match though, so that could be the issue I guess. I will test it tomorrow with "*"  to see if that helps.

Comment: Looks like notificationQueue isn't defined as an array

Comment: It is, but because this is just a short extract of the code, I forgot to include that.

Comment: Weirdly, having changed nothing of relevance to this code, it now works fine after just leaving it overnight... It's working now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Can provide a more complete example, including the content script? This code will fail as-is (you don't require the data utility object from the self module anywhere) and it is in the content script that you would need to listen for events sent via worker.port.emit, using self.port.on in the content script. For more on this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

Comment: See the edits I've made to the original post - this isn't the cause.

Comment: I see that, thanks for the extra context. My best suggestion would be to use a real regexp for the url you're trying to match.